# R Weighted Sampling Procedures

Tags: r, data.table, sample

```
data1=data.frame("School"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5),
"Group"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2),
"Class"=c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'),
"Size"=c(459,441,410,201,327,156,129,427,249,331,477,458,288,472,275,449,424,469,386,387,103,320,284,277,481,167,348,247,115,193))

data2=data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30),
"Group"=c(2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1),
"Class"=c('A','B','C','B','C','C','A','A','A','B','B','A','B','A','C','C','B','A','B','A','B','C','B','A','C','B','B','C','C','B'),
"Funds"=c(5,8,9,4,6,3,5,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,6,7,4,9,5,7,5,5,5,7,9,7,6,9,4,7),
"Ratio"=c(2,2,3,1,1,2,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,3,3,1,2,1,3,1,3),
"WEIGHT"=c(162,65,104,118,105,49,107,93,25,24,103,115,64,186,57,123,86,181,70,111,154,135,37,73,127,148,188,169,73,52))
```

I have data1 and data2 and hope to provide a simple example.

In data1 you see the 'School' number and the 'Size' of the 'Group' X 'Class' combinations.
In data2 you have information on 'Funds' and 'Ratio' for each of the 'Group' X 'Class' combinations. In data2 you also have 'WEIGHT' which equals to the sampling frame, which is to say that different 'ID's have different "weight" or importance.

I wish to create data3 which would look like this:

[image]

Overall I wish for data3 to have `sum(data1$Size)` rows. I wish to copy 'Size' rows for each 'School' X 'Group' X 'Class' combination from data1. Then I wish to sample with replacement by 'Group' X 'Class' 'Funds' and 'Ratio' from data2, using WEIGHTS to inform the probability of picking each row, to fill in data3.

Comment: @joran ........

Comment: If you sum the 'Size' column from data1 that will give you the expected number of rows in the output.

Comment: Group and Class are the interrsecting column names in both datasets, but they are also duplicated.  So, it is not clear how you want to merge

Comment: @akrun thanks so much. I think I have a challenge in explaining this but I will continue trying. Step 1 would be to make 'data3' by take 'data1' and expand it by 'Size'. So for example the first row is repeated 459 times, the second row is repeated 441 times, and so on and so forth. Then add empty columns 'Funds' and 'Ratio' to 'data3'. After this is complete, sample from 'Funds' and 'Ratio' from 'data2' by 'Group' and 'Class' using WEIGHTS to fill in values for 'Funds' and 'Ratio' in 'data3'

Comment: @akrun. i see! is it possible to conduct this process and ignore WEIGHTS for now? I will investigate them further and see how to convert them to probabilities

Comment: I expanded the data1 based on the 'Size' column, then split both datasets by 'Group', 'Class' and use `Map` to create the columns in first dataset based on a probablity created with 'WEIGHTS/sum(WEIGHTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `data.table` where we expand the data1 based on the 'Size' column, then split both datasets by 'Group', 'Class' and use Map to create the columns in first dataset based on a probablity created with `WEIGHT/sum(WEIGHT)` to be used in the `sample` for sampling the 'Funds', 'Ratio' column values, assign (`:=`) it to create new columns in the `list` and finally `rbind` the `list elements with`rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- setDT(data1)[rep(seq_len(nrow(data1)), Size)]
lst1 <- split(dt1, dt1[, .(Group, Class)])
lst2 <- split(data2, data2[c('Group', 'Class')], drop = TRUE)

out <- rbindlist(Map(function(x, y) {
            prb = y$WEIGHT/sum(y$WEIGHT)
            x[, c('Funds', 'Ratio') := 
           .(sample(y$Funds,  size = .N, replace = TRUE, prob=prb), 
            sample(y$Ratio,  size = .N, replace = TRUE, prob=prb) )]}, 
            lst1, lst2[names(lst1)]))

out[, Size := NULL]
sum(data1$Size)
#[1] 9750
nrow(out)
#[1] 9750
```

Comment: i think it is perfect i will now try on my real, messy data

Comment: thanks so much. it made me wait to accept it. I got an error...


> lst2 <- split(data2, data2[c('Group', 'Class')], drop = TRUE)


Error in `[.data.table`(data2, c("Group", "Class")) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: @bvowe In my example, `data2` is not data.table.  If you have a data.table, then use `split(data2, data2[, .(Group,Class)])`

Comment: @bvowe thank you.  does your other question solution works

Comment: i do not know if this is appropriate, but if you are available for a very brief chat i would be very interested to offer you a short-term paid consultation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210899/discussion-between-bvowe-and-akrun).